# Select from two columns (using Count and Filter) when count is greater than 0

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query which I am trying to modify:

```
SELECT 
(count (*) FILTER(Where "FailCode" BETWEEN 200 AND 202))/SUM(count (*) FILTER(Where "FailCode" BETWEEN 200 AND 3301)) OVER()*100 as "Col1",
(count (*) FILTER(Where "FailCode" BETWEEN 301 AND 356))/SUM(count (*) FILTER(Where "FailCode" BETWEEN 200 AND 3301)) OVER()*100 as "Col2"
FROM myTable
```

My results are the following:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 9.78 | 0.00 |

However, I am trying to display `Col2` only if its results are greater than 0.

This is what I've tried:

```
Select *
from(
    Select
(count (*) FILTER(Where "FailCode" BETWEEN 200 AND 202))/SUM(count (*) FILTER(Where "FailCode" BETWEEN 200 AND 3301)) OVER()*100 as "Col1",
(count (*) FILTER(Where "FailCode" BETWEEN 301 AND 356))/SUM(count (*) FILTER(Where "FailCode" BETWEEN 200 AND 3301)) OVER()*100 as "Col2" )
    from myTable) as t
where t.col1 > 0
```

But it's not working. I am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 2: from(
            ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
SQL state: 42601
Character: 14
```

I am expecting this result (because `Col1` is the only one with a result greater than zero):

| Col1 |
| --- |
| 9.78 |

Comment: You are getting this error because you have an extra closing parenthesis before `from myTable`. However, you cannot influence the number of columns based on the query result. At best, you can return NULL in `Col2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query needs to be modified to return `NULL` for `Col2` when its value is 0 or less by using a `CASE` statement, while keeping the structure of the result set consistent as per SQL requirements.

Try this

```
SELECT 
    (count(*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" BETWEEN 200 AND 202)) / SUM(count(*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" BETWEEN 200 AND 3301)) OVER() * 100 AS "Col1",
    CASE 
        WHEN (count(*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" BETWEEN 301 AND 356)) / SUM(count(*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" BETWEEN 200 AND 3301)) OVER() * 100 > 0 
        THEN (count(*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" BETWEEN 301 AND 356)) / SUM(count(*) FILTER (WHERE "FailCode" BETWEEN 200 AND 3301)) OVER() * 100 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS "Col2"
FROM myTable
```